# How to enable/disable OK button in AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I am struggling getting done a simple validation logic in a AlertDialog. Below my code. What happens in that setState() rebuilds the content of the alert, but not the actions. Thus the OK button does not enable/disable based on the validation logic.

I've been googleing a lot trying to figure it out, but I had not lukj so far.

Any hints?

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

import "package:easy_wallet/resources/constants.dart";

class EasyWalletApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: "EasyWallet", home: EasyWalletHomePage());
  }
}

class EasyWalletHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EasyWalletState createState() => _EasyWalletState();
}

class _EasyWalletState extends State<EasyWalletHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();

  String _name = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _name = "";
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _name = "";
    _nameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
          spacing: 15,
          children: [
            Text("No wallets yet..."),
            ElevatedButton(
                key: KEY_ADD_WALLET,
                child: const Text("➕"),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _showAddWalletDialog(context);
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _showAddWalletDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          print("build!");
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Add wallet'),
            content: Wrap(
              children: [
                Text("Insert wallet name:"),
                TextField(
                  controller: _nameController,
                  maxLength: 40,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    _name = value;
                    setState(() {
                      print("name: $_name");
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "eg: home"
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("pressed");
                  _name = "";
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: (!_isValidName()) ? null : () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  bool _isValidName() {
    print("address in validation: $_name");
    return _name.isNotEmpty;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(EasyWalletApp());
}
```

Comment: You can wrap AlertDialog with StatefulBuilder and then call setState of StatefulBuilder, So that it only rebuild the content of AlertDialog. for more info look https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the scoping of the context. I’d suggest moving all the logic inside the **AlertDialog**’s content into its own custom widget (including the logic to check for the **_isValidName()** and the buttons) so the widget rebuilds remain within that custom widget (also as a best practice).